# Invalid toolchain error with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
"Hello - Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?! Skipping...
```

I get the above message when I try to run a simple `HelloWorld` program as below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea as to why this is happening and how I could solve it would be useful
FYI : Im using the GNU GCC compiler at the moment, I tried changing this too but there was no use.

Comment: You probably installed the IDE minus the compiler. Also check [this](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=8603.0)

Comment: @Thrustmaster: Yup , fixed it and added my own answer! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Thrustmaster's comment. For anyone stuck with a similar problem in the future just go to `Settings->Compiler and Debugger->ToolChain Executables ->Click Auto Detect on the compiler's installation directory` . Presto! The IDE auto-detects the path and works!

Comment: Although questions like these do not belong here, glad that you were able to fix it. :)

Comment: where to find compiler's installation directory in Ubuntu 12.04? Before I've installed g++ using sudo apt-get install g++

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov: Your question is _significantly_ different from the one asked here.Use google!

Comment: why significantly? I've installed CodeBlocks in Ubuntu and when I try to compile helloworld program I get exactly the same error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: your earlier comment only asks for the default installation directory for Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a terminal (this assumes Linux or Mac OSX, and that GCC is installed):

```
g++ -o hello hello.cpp
```

Or, to install GCC on OSX, you have to install Xcode (the registration is free) and then go into **Xcode** → **Preferences** → **Downloads** → **Components**, and click on the install button next to "Command Line Tools".

To install GCC on Debian based Linux distros, use this: `sudo apt-get install g++`.

Comment: btw , this was for windows! :)

Comment: Oh. Then you can count out my answer. Sorry (I'm a Mac/Linux guy). I do applaud your decision to use GCC instead of Visual Studio and Visual C++. Just go look at the GCC website.

Comment: I wanted a *free* IDE that gave me solid Intellisense like support , so CodeBlocks it is ;)

Comment: @Kode: Exactly. Good for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings->Compiler and Debugger->ToolChain Executables
2. In Compilers installation directory, browse and select your MinGW installed Directory
3. Also for C compiler, browse and go to bin folder which is inside MinGW and select mingw32-gcc.exe
4. For C++ compiler, select mingw32-g++.exe from there
5. For Linker for dynamic libs , select mingw32-g++.exe from there
6. For Linker for static libs, select ar.exe from there
7. For Debugger, select gdb.exe from there
8. For Resource Compiler, select windres.exe from there
9. For Make program mingw32-make.exe from there

thats how it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your compiler settings are not configured. This is how i **solved** my issue

- Download **MinGW Instaltion Manager**
- Download `mingw32-gcc` and `mingw32-g++` compilers through **MingGW** and apply changes.
- go to Codeblocks and then `settings/toolchain executables`
- inside program files section configure the C compiler with `mingw32-gcc` and C++ compiler with `mingw32-g++` compiler