# "<project> - Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path within the compiler options is not setup correctly?

Tags: compiler-construction, path, linker, codeblocks, toolchain

I'm having trouble setting up CodeBlocks for a non-standard compiler. I've been struggling with it for 3 or 4 days now (on and off). I'm receiving the error:

```
"<project> - Debug" uses an invalid compiler. Probably the toolchain path
within the compiler options is not setup correctly?!
```

I need to use the following settings when building this project. It integrates with the FIPS Capable OpenSSL Library. The FIPS Capable OpenSSL Library was built from sources and installed in `/usr/local/ssl`:

```
$ export CC=`find /usr/local/ssl -name fipsld`
$ export FIPSLD_CC=`find /usr/bin -name g++`
$ echo $CC
/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld
$ echo $FIPSLD_CC
/usr/bin/g++
```

`fipsld` will compile `fips_premain.c` and perform some magic to ensure the module's signature is embedded in the resulting executable. If `fipsld` is not needed, then it simply invokes `CC` (hence the reason `FIPSLD_CC` needs to be set (also see Mike's comment on the circular dependency)).

I've done this a thousand times from the command line with makefiles, so I know it works.

**Environment**

Under **Settings -> Environment**, I have the following:

[image: CodeBlocks Environment]

**Compiler and Debugger**

Under **Settings -> Compiler and Debugger**, I have the following:

[image: CodeBlocks Program Files]

And:

[image: CodeBlocks Additional Paths]

**Project**

The project uses the FIPSLD compiler:

[image: CodeBlocks project compiler]

But when I attempt to build, I get the following:

[image]

I've also tried setting the compiler to the full specified path of `/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld`.

(And I've closed/opened CodeBlocks too many times to count, and cleaned this project numerous times to try an re-read configuration settings).

**Question**

How do I set the compiler to `/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld` in CodeBlocks?

And related: I have `gdb-7.6.2` installed in `/usr/local/bin`. But CodeBlocks uses `gdb-7.4` that comes with Debian, even though I have the paths specified for the debugger, too (that's the `usr/local` path to `/usr/local/bin/gdb`). Any ideas what's wrong here?

For completeness, this is not related to [Invalid toolchain error with Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170241/invalid-toolchain-error-with-codeblocks). In this SO question the OP did not have a toolchain installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "invalid compiler" difficulty can be solved as follows (at least it is
for me). I don't know whether this will be sufficient to let you build your
project.

I assume that the `fipsld` script is present and correct at `/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld`.

- In the Code::Blocks IDE, create a new compiler with the name of your
  choice that is a copy of GCC. (It looks like you have successfully done this)
- In the new compiler's settings, tab to **Toolchain executables** and make
  the following new settings:

  - **Compiler's installation directory** = `<empty>`
  - **Program files** - > **C compiler** = /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld
- Leave all other compiler settings unchanged and `OK`.
- Ensure that Code::Blocks has the Environment Variables Editor plugin installed
  as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/21064014/1362568
- In **Environment** -> **Environment Variables**, add the environment variable
  setting:

  CC = gcc

and `OK`. Do not add any **Additional paths** to the settings, unless you
need to later for some other reason.

I am now able to build C projects with the new compiler. Code::Blocks issues a
build-time warning `Can't find compiler executable in your configured
search paths for <compiler_name>`, but this is a false alarm.

The environment settings that are shown in your screen shot:

```
CC = /usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld
FIPSLD_CC = /usr/bin/g++
```

are off the mark because the first line of the `fipsld` script is:

```
CC=${FIPSLD_CC:-${CC}}
```

So, if you made the first of your two settings but not the second, the script
would default `$CC` to its own pathname - a circularity. And if you avoid this
by making both settings then the first is superfluous to Code::Blocks: 
it has no need for an environent variable that refers to 
`/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fpsld` because you have configured
that script as the compiler. It is only `fipsld` itself that wants `$CC`, referring to the
C compiler. So you might as well just set `CC = gcc`,
the host C compiler. `CC = g++` may be OK for your purposes, but conventionally
`CC` refers to your C compiler and your C++ compiler is referred to by `CXX`.

As for the problem of configuring /usr/local/bin/gdb to be invoked instead of /usr/bin/gdb,
I can only speak of v12.11, which I am running, but for 12.11 [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087272/1362568)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm getting there. Clearing the "Compiler's installation directory" and using "/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld" did the trick.

Comment: "if you made the first of your two settings but not the second, the script would default $CC to its own pathname - a circularity" - yeah, if you don't set `FIPSLD_CC`, then it creates a lot of problems (been there, done that...).