# How do you specify a debugger program in Code::Blocks 12.11?

Tags: codeblocks

I am trying to step through my program and I get the following message from Code::Blocks

```
Selecting target: 
Debug
ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings.
(For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes))
(For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out where I would type in gdb.exe.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- In the Code::Blocks IDE, navigate **Settings** -> **Debugger**
- In the tree control at the right, select **Common** -> **GDB/CDB debugger** -> **Common**.
- Then in the dialog at the left you can enter **Executable path** and choose 
  **Debugger type** = GDB or CDB, as well as configuring various other options.

Comment: Thanks. It seems slightly different for me. If I do Settings->Debugger I get a dialog box with Debugger settings and Common at the top. On the left is an off-shaped "tree" with Common (up) and GCB/CDB Debugger (sideways) coming out of a box and Default descending from GDB/CDB Debugger. If I click on Default (DGB/CDG Defbugger->Default) I get the parts that you mention last above (on the right).

Answer (score 21):

1. Go to *Settings -> Debugger -> Common -> GDB/CDB Debugger -> Default*
2. Click on `executable path` to find the address to `gdb32.exe`
3. Locate where your codeblock is installed
4. Follow the given path:

*CodeBlock -> MinGW -> bin -> gdb32.exe* (locate it and double click on it)

5. Press OK

Answer (score 11):

For Code::Blocks 17.12.

1. Visit http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=MinGW_installation#TDM-GCC
2. Follow installation's instructions.
3. Alternatively I suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309591/installing-mingws-gdb-exe-for-code-blocks/49067766#49067766) post.

Regards.

Comment: The link is dead, that's why links should not be used.

Comment: Mr. Ruli, please let me express you my glad for given me the opportunity to update my answer. In 3rd step  click "this" and follow instructions. I have updated address of TDM-GCC installer. Regards.

Comment: M. Ruli, please let me tell you that link is alive. After clicking  http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=MinGW_installation#TDM-GCC, click the link TDM-GCC, just below paragraph header TDM-GCC. Regards.

Answer (score 7):

1. Click on settings in top tool bar;
2. Click on debugger;
3. In tree, highlight "gdb/cdb debugger" by clicking it
4. Click "create configuration"
5. Add "gdb.exe" (no quotes) as a configuration
6. Delete default configuration
7. Click on `gdb.exe` that you created in the tree (it should be the only one) and a dialogue will appear to the right for "executable path" with a button to the right.
8. Click on that button and it will bring up the file that codeblocks is installed in. Just keep clicking until you create the path to the `gdb.exe` (it sort of finds itself).

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [tutorial to install GBD](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm).

Usually [GNU Debugger](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/download/) might not be in your computer, so you would install it first. The installation steps are basic "configure", "make", and "make install".

Once installed, try `which gdb` in terminal, to find the executable path of GDB.

Answer (score 1):

Download codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe instead of codeblocks-13.12setup.exe from the official site. Here 13.12 is the latest version so far.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Settings >> Debugger`.
2. Now as you can see in the image below. There's a tree. `Common->GDB/CDB Debugger -> Default`.
   [image]
3. Click on executable path (on the right) to find the address to gdb32.exe.
4. Click `gdb32.exe >> OK`.

Answer (score 0):

Click on settings in top tool bar;

Click on debugger;

In tree, highlight "gdb/cdb debugger" by clicking it

Click "create configuration"

Click default configuration, a dialogue will appear to the right for "executable path" with a button to the right.

Click on that button and it will bring up the file that codeblocks is installed in. Just keep clicking until you create the path to the gdb.exe (it sort of finds itself).