# Installing MinGW's gdb.exe for Code Blocks

Tags: c++, mingw

Hey guys I really need help.

I have recently started programming C++ again and I am trying to get Code Blocks up and running but it keeps failing because of this error.

"ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings."

Understandably this means there isn't a debugger program so I have to download one. I tried to find the gdb.exe for MinGW but I can't find it at all. I just end up with the MinGW's Installation Manager and being left confused.

Are there any tutorials about using the MinGW written for beginners or anyone willing to help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GDB comes with CodeBlocks when you install it with the MinGW option.

Comment: Ok I have reinstalled it with the correct option but I am now cornered with a new error

"Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'."

What could be the problem now?

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials on the Code Blocks site. That being said, questions asking for tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Steps to add gdb.exe
Open MinGW Installation Manager 
select package "mingw32-gdb" from the list.
Then select "Apply Changes" in Installation menu.
This will automatically install gdb.exe in the path C:\MinGW\bin.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me suggest you debugger program TDM-GCC. For download and install visit

http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=MinGW_installation

Because a debugger program (toolchain) is very complex undertaking, is not standard in Code::Blocks. You must download it and install on Code::Blocks.

*Note*: It is impossible copy and paste images here. In the case linked page changes, I, or another one, should suggest new link.

However following are instructions according to images and my experience.

1. Download TDM-GCC from https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/download/ click [tdm64-gcc-10.3.0-2.exe] and run it.
2. In **Wizard Action** window - Click [**Create**].
3. In **Select Edition** window - If **MinGW/TDM (32-bit)** is not checked, check it. Click [Next>].
4. In **Licence Changes** window - Click [Next>].
5. In **New Instalation: Instalation Directory** window - If text box is "C:\TDM-GCC-32", it's okay. If is not, click [Browse ...], and navigate: C:\ > TDM-GCC-32 > click [OK]. Now text box is C:\TDM-GCC-32. Click [Next>].

If a small window appears saying *The directory TDM-GCC-32 is not empty! Are you sure you want to install here?*. Click [Yes].

6. In **New Installation: Download Mirror** window - Click [Next>].
7. In **New Installation: Choose Components** window - Check whether *Add to PATH* box is checked. Actually is checked. Click [Install].
8. In **Installing** window - Wait till [Next] become black. Then click it. Even if **Instalation Failed** window appears click [Next].
9. In **Completing the TDM-GCC Setup Wizard** window - Click [Finish].
10. Go to Code Blocks > Settings > Compiler.

10a. In **Global compiler settings** window click "Toolchain executables". Just below, find "Compiler's installation directory". If the below text field is C:\TDM-GCC-32, it's okay. If not, click the [...] at the end of the field. In "Select directory" wizard, navigate to C:\TDM-GCC-32. Now "Folder:" should be TDM-GCC-32. Click [Select a folder] in "Select directory" wizard.

10b. In **Global compiler settings**. Below red "Note:..." find "Program Files" > "Debuger". If text field reads "GDB/CDB debuger : Default", it's okay, click [OK]. If not, click the down arrow at the end of the field > choose "GDB/CDB debuger : Default". Check that text field is "GDB/CDB debuger : Default". Click [OK].

11. Go to Code Blocks > Settings > Debugger... . In **Common** window, left list, click "Default". If "Executable path:"'s text field is "C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\gdb32.exe", it's okay, click [OK]. If not, click [...] button and navigate C: > TDM-GCC-32 > bin > click gdb32 (or gdb32.exe) file > click [open] in "Select executable file" wizard. "Executable path:" should be C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\gdb32.exe. Click [OK]. Now you can debug your program.
12. If Debugger does not function, close Code Blocks and restart them.

Regards.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Hey guys I suggest a better way. Download "gdb.exe" from the [Internet](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=gdb) and copy it to the below path.

```
C:\MinGW\Bin
```

It's really works. I did it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).