# Code blocks debugging issue

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to run a simple linked list program in code blocks, but I am not able to run the program and i getting the below error :

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:
Default Building to ensure sources are up-to-date Selecting target: 
 Debug ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings. 
(For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes)) 
(For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))
```

I tried some of the posts given here on Stack Overflow, but that setting is already there in the code blocks.

Comment: In your **Settings** -> **Debugger settings** -> **GDB/CDB debugger** -> **Default** -> **Executable path**, what does it say?

Comment: its empty.. coming as red blank field

Comment: Please let me suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309591/installing-mingws-gdb-exe-for-code-blocks/49067766#49067766) post. With regards and friendship.

Comment: Please let me suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309591/installing-mingws-gdb-exe-for-code-blocks/49067766#49067766) post. With regards and friendship

Comment: Please let me suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309591/installing-mingws-gdb-exe-for-code-blocks/49067766#49067766) post. With regards and friendship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out where `gdb.exe` is located in whatever GCC toolchain you
are using with Code::Blocks, e.g:-

- For MinGW:    C:\MingGW\bin\gdb.exe,
- For mingw-w64:    C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe
- For TDM-GCC:  C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gdb.exe

If you can't find it then the root of the problem is that the debugger is (no longer)
installed.

If you find it, then enter its full pathname in **Settings** -> **Debugger settings** -> **GDB/CDB debugger** -> **Default** -> **Executable path**.
Code::Blocks will check the pathname you enter and if it can't find it then the edit-field will turn red. Otherwise, OK out
and the debugger will then work.

If the directory containing `gdb.exe` is in your `PATH` then you can simply enter `gdb.exe` in the field.

Comment: I could not find the path where gdb.exe was located so I installed other version of code blocks, in that executable path contains the gdb.exe in the field and now its working fine. Thanks Mike :)