# Code::Blocks debug doesn't run and shows error

Tags: c, codeblocks

i have seen an answer to my similar question.but with that answer, my problem is not resolved.
I run debugger for program C written on Code::Blocks, but debug doesn't run and shows error.

```
Default Building to ensure sources are up-to-date Selecting target: 
 Debug ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings. 
(For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes)) 
(For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))
```

"this is the answer i have seen before"
[Code blocks debugging issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592177/code-blocks-debugging-issue)

```
Find out where gdb.exe is located in whatever GCC toolchain you are using with Code::Blocks, e.g:-

For MinGW: C:\MingGW\bin\gdb.exe,
For mingw-w64: C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe
For TDM-GCC: C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\gdb.exe
If you can't find it then the root of the problem is that the debugger is (no longer) installed.

If you find it, then enter its full pathname in Settings -> Debugger settings -> GDB/CDB debugger -> Default -> Executable path. Code::Blocks will check the pathname you enter and if it can't find it then the edit-field will turn red. Otherwise, OK out and the debugger will then work.

If the directory containing gdb.exe is in your PATH then you can simply enter gdb.exe in the field.
```

I have followed it. but in my case it only found gdb32.exe instead of gdb.exe. And I have followed with gdb323.exe but my problem is not resolved.

[image: gdb32.exe]

Comment: On the internet, please do not write sentences with purely capital letters, it is considered rude (screaming).

Comment: And, caps aside - please *link* the question and answers that *didn't* solve your problem.

Comment: I don't know codeblocks, but the issue with your program is that you don't want the `&` before `&b[0]`. For the string that you're assembling character by character (`char a[] = "abc";` would be simpler) you do want a pointer to the string for %s, so you do want `&a[1]`, but for the %d you want the actual value which is `b[0]` not `&b[0]`.

Comment: I think the screenshot *is* relevant. I don't think the **GDB path** should go into that *Debugger initialization commands*, those are instead the commands that Code::Blocks should send to the *debugger interface*. I am not sure though if something *else* should go there

Comment: As @AnttiHaapala said, the GDB path should not be put in the initialization command field.