# debug c program in code::block 13.12

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

I am using [Code Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/home) 13.12. I am unable to run any program except hello word. The error i am getting is "Debug ERROR: You need to specify a debugger program in the debuggers's settings. (For MinGW compilers, it's 'gdb.exe' (without the quotes)) (For MSVC compilers, it's 'cdb.exe' (without the quotes))". Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Check out [this resolved thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083560/how-do-you-specify-a-debugger-program-in-codeblocks-12-11

Answer (score 1):

You can set the debugger for Code Blocks under Settings->Debugger->GDB/CDB Debugger->Default->Executable path. You will need either [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [MSCV](https://www.visualstudio.com/) (The community edition is free) installed.