# Getting the error while run the debuger in code blocks

Tags: c, debugging

Here is the error massage in the debuger block.
I have already set the executable path and I have create an empty project also.

```
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: This question has been [asked and answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21087272/645128).

Answer (score 1):

If your executable path has spaces in it, remove them and CodeBlocks should find the exec fine.

Comment: Is it the only way to solve it?, I cannot remove the blank spaces in the path because of cloud storage folder settings. So, I would be grateful if anybody knew a different solution.